# Use Mage_Uploader in custom form in store frontend

Tags: magento-1, frontend, upload, ce-1.9.3.0

Magento 1.9.3 (also: 1.x with security patch SUPEE-8788) introduced the `Mage_Uploader` module, a new file upload widget without Flash. The core only uses it in the admin area (product images, CMS), but I would like to have it on a custom form in the frontend too, to allow multiple file uploads.

What do I need to do to make it available in the frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use it with the following steps:

- Copy `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml` to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/media/uploader.phtml`
- Add the following JavaScript files via layout XML:

  ```
  <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
          <name>lib/uploader/flow.min.js</name>
      </action>
      <action method="addJs">
          <name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow.js</name>
      </action>
      <action method="addJs">
          <name>lib/uploader/fusty-flow-factory.js</name>
      </action>
      <action method="addJs">
          <name>mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js</name>
      </action>
  </reference>
  ```
- Include the `Mage_Uploader` translations in the frontend (in my modules `config.xml`):

  ```
  <frontend>
      <translate>
          <modules>
              <Mage_Uploader>
                  <files>
                      <default>Mage_Uploader.csv</default>
                  </files>
              </Mage_Uploader>
          </modules>
      </translate>
  </frontend>
  ```
- Add the relevant CSS from the admin theme:

  ```
  .uploader .buttons { margin-bottom: 10px; }
  .uploader .clear:after { display:block; clear:both; content:"."; font-size:0; line-height:0; height:0; overflow:hidden; }

  .uploader .file-row { width:600px; padding:0.5em 0.6em; margin:0.5em 0.6em; border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#f9f9f9; /*vertical-align:middle;*/ }
  .uploader .file-row-narrow { width: auto; margin: 0 0 2px 40px; }
  .uploader .file-row .file-info { float:left; }
  .uploader .file-row-info { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }
  .uploader .file-row-info .file-info-name  { font-weight:bold; }
  .uploader .file-row .progress-text { float:right; font-weight:bold; }
  .uploader .file-row .delete-button { float:right; }
  .uploader .progress { border:1px solid #f0e6b7; background-color:#feffcc; }
  .uploader .error { border:1px solid #aa1717; background-color:#ffe6de; }
  .uploader .error .progress-text { padding-right:10px; }
  .uploader .complete { border:1px solid #90c898; background-color:#e5ffed; }
  ```
- Include the uploader in my form with a block method like this:

  ```
  public function getUploaderHtml()
  {
      $uploader = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('uploader/multiple');
      $uploader->getUploaderConfig()->setTarget($this->getUrl('my/upload/controller'));
      return $uploader->toHtml()
  }
  ```
- write a controller (as specified in `setTarget()` above) which handles the file upload. It should return the result of `Varien_File_Uploader::save()` as JSON or in case of error:

  ```
  json_encode(['error' => 'error message', 'error_code' => 123]);
  ```